Adding WKT to VRT using R / LidR
I am trying to work through this error after adding a VLR to a LAS.
I'm using a custom local projection that does not have an EPSG code, hence trying to add the WKT string as a VRT.
> header(las)
File signature:           LASF 
File source ID:           0 
Global encoding:
 - GPS Time Type: Standard GPS Time 
 - Synthetic Return Numbers: no 
 - Well Know Text: CRS is GeoTIFF 
 - Aggregate Model: false 
Project ID - GUID:        00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 
Version:                  1.2
System identifier:         
Generating software:      LASzip DLL 3.4 r3 (191111) 
File creation d/y:        52/2024
header size:              227 
Offset to point data:     1696 
Num. var. length record:  1 
Point data format:        3 
Point data record length: 34 
Num. of point records:    38199174 
Num. of points by return: 29315351 6745793 1814748 295580 27702 
Scale factor X Y Z:       1e-04 1e-04 1e-04 
Offset X Y Z:             2803890 1407216 8429.328 
min X Y Z:                2801940 1404295 8331.521 
max X Y Z:                2805840 1410138 8527.79 
Variable Length Records (VLR):
   Variable Length Record 1 of 1 
       Description: descriptor here 
Error in if (vlr$`record ID` == 34735) { : argument is of length zero

To get to this point I've done the following - in simplest terms:

# Increment the number of variable length records by 1
las@header$`Number of variable length records` <- las@header$`Number of variable length records` + 1

# Assuming projcs_wkt contains the WKT string
vlr <- list(
  description = "descriptor here",
  data = projcs_wkt
)

#Add VLR to the LAS header
las@header@VLR <- list(vlr)

I've also muddled with setting the Offset to points value as the VLR size + 227, and tried key/value pairs and simple strings in the vlr list definition.  I don't think it is the string itself, more likely my approach.
I've also tried using this function to generate the VLR as follows:
header1 <- header_set_wktcs(vlr, projcs_wkt)
header2 <- header_set_wktcs(header, projcs_wkt)
Perhaps someone has seen this error before and can point me in the right direction!

You must

Change the WKT global bit encoding
remove the GeoTIFF CRS
add a wkt string

library(lidR)
f = system.file("extdata", "example.laz", package="rlas")
las = readLAS(f)
las@header@PHB[["Global Encoding"]][["WKT"]] = TRUE
las@header@VLR[["GeoKeyDirectoryTag"]] = NULL
wkt(las) = 'PROJCS["NAD27 / UTM zone 16N",GEOGCS["NAD27",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1927",SPHEROID["Clarke 1866",6378206.4,294.9786982139006,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7008"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6267"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4267"]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-87],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["metre",1,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH],AUTHORITY["EPSG","26716"]]'

o = tempfile(fileext = ".las")
writeLAS(las, o)

readLAS(o)


Thanks.  Will give that a try!

This worked great, thank you!  One follow up question, how do I edit the VLR Description tag which defaults to:  Variable Length Records (VLR):
Variable Length Record 1 of 1
Description: by LAStools of rapidlasso GmbH
WKT OGC COORDINATE SYSTEM: COMPD_CS["CCD_LOCAL...

Please open a new question with a well-defined problem
